# How to add C# project reference to cruise control.net

Tags: .net-4.0, c#-4.0, cruisecontrol.net, msbuild-4.0

I am new to cruise control. I have added the project using ccnet.config file and it shows and gives a compilation error. I found that the project is dependent on a reference project that is not being compiled by cruise control. how to fix this.

lets say I am building project A which is dependent on project B. Project B is added as a reference in project A. all the projects are in source control. I added the project a to cruise control by configuring ccnet.config file. when I click build is says some methods are missing that are part of project B. When I checked the folder I found that cruise control is not getting the latest version of project B from source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally C# project files include a references section which reference dependent projects. Ensure that the source code for the dependencies is available to the source project in the same relative directories as the .csproj file is using to reference them. Compiling the C# project using msbuild will automatically compile the dependencies as well.